# dropdown menu according to selected value in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get selected value from database in html dropdown menu.
I am using this code, but, I am getting error in it:

```
<option value='ADMIN' <?php($key=='ADMIN')??>selected <?php :''?> >Admin</option>
```

I have tried this one too:

```
 <option value='SUPERVISOR' <?php($key=='SUPERVISOR')?'selected':''?> >Supervisor</option>
```

But, I am not getting correct output.

Comment: What output are you getting? What error message do you get?

Comment: That isn't even valid PHP code. Not even close.

Comment: when I use first opetion, then I am getting syntax error. and in second one I am getting nothing. html cannot even load rest of the page after this code.

Comment: Try using some spaces...what in the world is `<?php : ''?>` supposed to do? Are you trying to split up a ternary?

Comment: You didn't "echo" your ternary statement `<option value='ADMIN' <?php echo $key=='ADMIN' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Admin</option>`

Comment: still there is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<option value='ADMIN' <?php echo ($key=='ADMIN') ? 'selected=selected' : ''; ?>>Admin</option>
```

Comment: The presence of the `selected` attribute is enough. It doesn't need a value. Looks good otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your formatting is wrong. That's probably why you are getting syntax errors.

You need to insert some whitespace after the opening PHP tag. For example:

```
<?php ($key == 'ADMIN')
```

Second, you can't split up a ternary operator like that. You need to do something like:

```
<?php ($key == 'ADMIN') ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```

Finally, you need to echo output.

```
<?php echo ($key == 'ADMIN') ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```

Do the same thing for SUPERVISOR key.

---

If you are receiving errors, and want help with them, then you need to tell us what the errors say.